# Add hyperlink to excel column where Hyperlink is URL+Cell Content

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-formula, vba

I have a ton of columns in excel where the cell value can be searched against a website's search engine. I want to create a new column where it directly links to that search result. The format of the website is: "website.com/search.php?=SEARCH_QUERY" Where Search query is whatever you're searching for.

In this case I want to replace Search_Query with the contents of my cell. I can do this easily in awk using "awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}$1="website.com/search.php?="$1' file" but I'm wondering if it's possible to do it using only excel on a windows machine.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to select a cell then run this line `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="website.com/search.php?=" & ActiveCell.Value` , if this is what you want then we can loop through all cells in the column and change `Selection` to target cell.

Comment: The excel formula would `=HYPERLINK("website.com/search.php?=" & A2)` assuming A2 is where the value is. You can do this and drag down (or across). No need for VBA at all to accomplish this.